# Cannot call method in objective c

Tags: objective-c, json, ios7, methods, xcode5

I'm having difficulty understanding how to call a method. Here's the code:

```
- (void)beachJSON
{
// Build the string to call Beach API
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://nrw-bwq-dev-api.azurewebsites.net/api/Pull"];

// Create NSURL string from formatted string
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

// Setup and start async download
NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL: url];
NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
[connection release];
[request release];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
// Store incoming data into a string
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


results = [jsonString JSONValue];


}

- (NSArray *)getBeachList {
[self beachJSON];

return results;
}
```

I call getBeachList from another class to populate 'results', beachJSON is called fine but I need to call

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
```

Within

```
- (NSArray *)getBeachList
```

i.e. right here

```
- (NSArray *)getBeachList {
[self beachJSON];
//This is where I want to call it to populate results before it is returned
return results;
}
```

Calling getBeachList will call beachJSON but the connection method will be skipped over leaving 'results' nil

If i try simply putting

```
[self connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data]
```

I get a expected expression error on that line.

I'm pretty new to objective c so any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You should not call `connection:didReceiveData:` by yourself. This is an event which is only supposed to be fired by the `NSURLConnection` instance. As far as I can see the only thing you are missing is the `start` call, which actually makes the `NSURLConnection` perform the request.

Try this:

```
NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL: url];
NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
[connection start];
```

Then you should see that your `NSURLConnection` instance will call your implementation of  `connection:didReceiveData:`.

If you want to be sure that your data is fully loaded you should be using this event instead:

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
```

The `connection:didReceiveData:` will be called multiple times if your data size is large enough. Every time the `NSURLConnection` receives data it will invoke `connection:didReceiveData:`. `connectionDidFinishLoading:` will only be called once when all your data is ready.

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified that getBeachList is called from another class. So every time it is called, beachJSON works but connection method gets skipped over. This gives me results returning as nil.

Comment: Specified what? :) Please do edit your question if you are not satisfied with it.

Comment: I've edited my question further to clarify what I'm trying to do. Should have made sure it was 100% clear when I posted it D:

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to call this method.
It's a delegate method of NSURLConnection.
What you need is to set a delegate for connection and method will be called by connection when it downloads any data.

Comment: Could you please expand on what you mean by setting a delegate for connection?

Comment: @Marushiru, sorry, you did that in connection initialization. if you wrote [.. initWithRequest:... delegate:self] then connection object will call -connection:didReceiveData:.
You should not return anything from getBeachList method. You need to set strong reference to connection instance. You have to [connection start].
Download will start and you will get pieces of data as arguments in didReceiveData:. You should concatenate the contents of each data object delivered to build up the complete data for a URL load. You will get more info if you read "URL Loading system programming guide".